# IE8 breaks when using two selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm styling a table using CSS and I realised that IE8 doesn't support `:nth-child`

So before I added support for IE8, the css looked like so

```
.my-comments table.comments-list tr td:nth-child(1){width:18%;}
```

Then I added another selector like so

```
.my-comments table.comments-list tr td:nth-child(1), .my-comments table.comments-list tr .datecol{width:18%;}
```

IE8 doesn't like this, it wont recognise the 2nd selector but if I take out the first one like below then it works

```
.my-comments table.comments-list tr .datecol{width:18%;}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Obviously I could just use the above code but I'd like to leave in both selectors for future browsers

Comment: I would try making the style separately (without the comma). IE8 is probably not recognizing the :nth child and skipping the declaration.

Comment: @Grillz Thanks very much, works perfectly. If you want to leave this as an answer, I'll accept!

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll throw it down in the answers.

Comment: IE8 is following the rules here. See unknown selector, discard entire rule.

Comment: Then the question is : who made that rule??? It makes no sense to me. How is this different to writing two different blocks with two different selectors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would try making the style separately (without the comma). IE8 is probably not recognizing the :nth child and skipping the declaration.

Answer (score 4):

If you would still like your `nth-child(1)` style to work in IE8 (with out having to add the `.datecol` class) you could change your CSS to the following:

```
.my-comments table.comments-list tr td:first-child + td {
    width:18%;
}
```

The above code would target the second `td` - which is what I believe you are aiming to do with `nth-child(1)` and is support across a wider range of browsers.

Comment: Good call, since `:first-child` is part of CSS2.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I'm missing something here. Can't you just separate them into 2 different lines?

```
.my-comments table.comments-list tr td:nth-child(1){width:18%;}
.my-comments table.comments-list tr .datecol{width:18%;}
```

Comment: while you can do this, it goes against the DRY principle. :/